# How to enable ssl function in sybase database？

Tags: sybase

I installed the Sybase database using the latest datagrip/sybase image. Now I want the database to support SSL authentication. How should I configure the certificate and key?

I used the isql command line tool to enable the ssl option, but I did not find how to configure the certificate and key. I tried searching for this, but did not find any relevant answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While OP has mentioned using the `isql` command line tool, `isql` can be used to access at least 3 of the SAP(Sybase) RDBMS products ... ASE, IQ, SQLAnywhere.  This answer assumes OP is using ASE ...

There are several steps involved in setting up SSL, with many of the steps depending on your specific situation, eg:

- requesting and authorizing the SSL certificate (3rd party vs self-generated? self-generated with what tool?)
- updating the ASE server's directory entries (linux/unix/`interfaces` vs windows/`sql.ini`? configuring ASE to allow SSL, non-SSL, or both connection types?)
- matching cipher suites and TLS protocol with your application capabilities

I'd recommend reviewing the [SSL Overview](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/2705a3b1e3df4514ab089cfedf87750d/a946ebcabc2b1014a699adf27c9f6315.html) chapter in the Security Administration Guide.

After reviewing the manual and determining the steps needed for your environment, if you run into problems configuring your ASE server then consider asking a new question related to the specific issue you're trying to address.